Using ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project : I am trying to access controller and its attributes from middleware
In my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API based project, I have a middleware which is being executed for every request. I want to avoid this situation and want it to only execute for those API controllers which have the [Authorize] attribute applied to them. For this purpose, I am trying to access the controller and then its attributes, but I am unable to do it.
The WeatherForecastController doesn't have an [Authorize] attribute, so I do not want to run the code in this middleware for this API controller.
Middleware
public class CustomRequestMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomRequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var endpoint = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;

        await _next(context);
    }
}

Program.cs:
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

        // Add services to the container.        
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        // For Identity
        builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Adding Authentication
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                        {
                           ......
                        })

            // Adding Jwt Bearer
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                        {
                           .......
                            };
                        });

        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseCustomRequestMiddleware();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
}

WeatherForecastController:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
                    {
                        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
                    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                        {
                            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                        })
                        .ToArray();
    }
}

Appreciate your guidance and support.

You don't need the controller at all. Authorization is performed by the authentication middleware, not the controller, before the controller gets created. Put app.UseCustomRequestMiddleware(); after app.UseAuthorization(). The ASP.NET Core Middleware Overview page shows how the order of middleware affects execution and how to properly register your own middleware

@PanagiotisKanavos I have gone through the middleware link. Just a quick question that our custom Middlewares will always come after the Authorization ?

Only if you register it after UseAuthorization. The order in the docs is the recommended one and depends on the order of the .Use calls. As the docs say : You have full control over how to reorder existing middlewares or inject new custom middlewares as necessary for your scenarios.
